# Keycloak restarts continuously after DB backup restore

Tags: keycloak

i am using a postgres sql as database for my keycloak (version 14.0.0) as distroless docker image.
After i have restored a SQL dump from my keycloak, it's continuosly restarting with the following error message:

```
User with username 'su_0317912' already added to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json'
```

I have no idea why this message appears, because this user `'su_0317912'` doesn't exists in my database. There is another `su`-user created by Keycloak before the backup, so why is Keycloak even trying to create one ?

Since the keycloak container is restarting the whole time, i can't connect to the bash after it's in the restarting loop.

Any help and tips would be very nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved. In my case there was the KEYCLOAK_ADMIN su_0317912 set in environment variables. But after restore there was another su allready in DB. But the error message is somehow confusing, because not the su_0317912 is already added, just another user.

Is only one su_* user allowed in the database ?